# Error with Symfony installation

Tags: php, symfony

I created a new Symfony project using composer:

`composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition ./`

After vendor downloads and the parameter.ini file questions I get the following error:

`PHP Parse error:  parse error, expecting`')'' in /Users/..../app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 20`

I inspected the file

```
class appDevDebugProjectContainer extends Container
{
    private static $parameters = array(
        'kernel.root_dir' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)),     //LINE 20
        'kernel.environment' => 'dev',
```

I don't see why this is causing an error but removed the `dirname(dirname(__DIR__))` and I hardcoded the absolute path.

I tried to run ./app/console and got another error within the appDevDebug file, another reference to `__DIR__`.

I was able to get through a few of these by hardcoding the path but eventually got to a different error message altogether (still within the appDevDebug file).

This file is autogenerated so I decided to stop going down that path... Any idea what would be causing this?

I have run `php app/check.php` and it says my system is configured to run symfony. I also have older installs of symfony (2.4, 2.5) on the same machine and they run fine.

Comment: can you try this:
    php app/console cache:clear --verbose

Comment: I get the same error. I also get this error if I run `sudo rm -rf app/cache/*` and then run `app/console`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change composer.json:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6",
...
```

Previously it used dev branch

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.6.x-dev",
```

After that change it went smoothly.

**UPDATE**

Actually you might have to use service.**xml** not service.yml. For some reason service.yml does not work for me (it is ignored).

Answer (score 0):

I'm researching the same issue and found those solutions so far:

Have you set your timezone for the CLI php.ini ? You can check with this:

```
php --info | grep timezone
```

Alternatively you can clear the cache and try again:

```
rm -Rf app/cache/dev (prod instead of dev for a productive environment)
```

Comment: The timezone is set, Default timezone and date.timezone => America/Los_Angeles.

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache `sudo rm -rf app/cache/*` and still get same error